# Search people by company on Facebook using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to search the list of people on Facebook using the API. I know Facebook has this function but it is on the web platform. I want to take this advantage into my application so I think the API is the only way I can do it.

I also know another application can do the similar thing is the Twigmore (http://twigmore.com). They can search people by location (within its own application). Does anyone know how does they manage this?

Any advice is highly appreciated,
Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify location and work in the friends API call with `friends_location` and `friends_work_history` permissions

`graph.faceobok.com/me/friends?fields=location,work`